# MVC pattern combined with Repository pattern in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, repository-pattern, laravel-10

So far I understand, a repository pattern contains the methods to save data in the database. It is useful to encapsulate this access to the database from the other parts of the business logic.

A Model, also a part to handle the access to the DB and prepare date before they where send or stored.

If I combine both, so I will use a repository in a model, I've a segregation of preparing the data and access to the DB.

Is this a good to follow this concept in Laravel?  In Laravel I can execute the methods like `orderBy(...)`, `all()` and `where(...)` in the model.

Or is the assumption correct, that the model is just the data layer for the Controller? Should I use the Model only for purpose of the Controller and the repository for all other stuff of using data.

Comment: Repository layer with Eloquent - very bad practice.

Comment: @Maksim can you explain why?

Comment: because an active record model has all the ability to save/update/delete/etc records by itself (it is a repository and an instance of a record all in one); there is nothing stopping you from directly doing things with the model ... if you had a layer that was returning some DTOs they would only contain data which would keep your separation between all of this ..... perhaps that is why people don't like it

Comment: I'll add another experience backed +1 to this. Don't try to shoehorn the repository pattern into Laravel. You give up some choices when you select a framework, and while Laravel leaves a lot of options open - including the ability to "technically" implement repositories - you should consider this a choice made for you by the framework. To do it, you'll add a lot of extra code and get very few if any of the benefits. If you still insist on using the repository pattern, you should probably drop eloquent altogether or just use the `DB` facade to do your queries.

Comment: i know people who use Laravel and use Doctrine so they don't have to deal with Active Record Models, Eloquent in this case .... you certainly can build repositories but just understand you are losing abstraction with the Models as they have the ability to do what the Repository is doing so the separation is only conceptual and not via any implementation

Comment: Right, the separation is based more on convention, it's not really enforceable. Which to me is too risky. Plus ever since I started using Laravel, the reasoning behind using repositories was to make it possible to switch ORMs - which looks really cool and useful in a demo, but it's a use case I have never heard of actually happening (someone will probably prove me wrong here now that I've said it publicly)

Comment: I love the concept of abstracting the layer and if you can enforce the rules on yourself that is great but only self-enforcement is probably an anti-pattern in some way :)   good points @BrianThompson

Comment: OK, that means that the Model is the best choice. Also for processes which Not called direct from a Controller. Is this correct?